# Display and scroll validatation error to nth UITextfield inside UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

Display validation error to nothing  `UITextfield` inside `UITableView`

Lets say a table has 10 rows with `UITextfield`  but only 3 are visible at a time, how would I show error on validation on some specific `UITextfield` and scroll to it.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind there is a cell reusing so when you enter a data in a textfield it will be reused by another so , when the cell is going to hide store the value of the text inside the corresponding index in the model array and in `cellForRow` clear the cell textfield contents before using it , also it's better to validate the array in the model and scroll to the array index (row index) that failed in validation , you can use code snippet like this to scroll

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: scrollPosition, section: 0)
tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .middle, animated: true)
```